# SQLite and ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have a `ListView` in my class, I have a cursor regarding a number `x` which is incrementing each time, I am using this cursor in a `ListView` but at the time when I am using this `x` only one row is showing in the `ListView`. I want to show all the lists regarding the incrementing value. My code is as follows:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            do {
                int x = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("trainId"));
                String s1 = "SELECT * FROM route_table WHERE trainId=" + x + " AND stationId=" + FromStationId + ";";
                String s2 = "SELECT * FROM route_table WHERE trainId=" + x + " AND stationId=" + ToStationId + ";";
                final Cursor c1 = SQ.rawQuery(s1, null);
                final Cursor c2 = SQ.rawQuery(s2, null);
                if (c1 != null && c1.moveToFirst()) {
                    i = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    c1.close();
                }
                if (c2 != null && c2.moveToFirst()) {
                    j = c2.getInt(c2.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    c2.close();
                }
                if (i < j) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "My Train is:" + x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String fstring = "SELECT * FROM train_table WHERE _id=" + x + ";";
                    final Cursor c3 = SQ.rawQuery(fstring, null);
                    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tiimetable_list);
                    CursorAdapterTimeTable myc = new CursorAdapterTimeTable(this, c3);
                    lv.setAdapter(myc);
                    // List(x);
                }
                break;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            continue;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: X which is in the query is incrementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one row is showing, because every time the query is executed a new adapter is created.

Try this to get all items where "_id" are greater than 0:

```
String fstring = "SELECT * FROM train_table WHERE _id > 0";
final Cursor c3 = SQ.rawQuery(fstring, null);
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tiimetable_list);
CursorAdapterTimeTable myc = new CursorAdapterTimeTable(this, c3);
lv.setAdapter(myc);
```

Comment: But what shall I do when i want to get the list when x is some incremented value,,which is getting incremented each time

Comment: You'll need to change your adapter to accept new items, including previous, then call `myc.notifyDatasetChanged()`

I recommend you to use "ArrayAdapter", see:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html